# How to upload file to Dropbox through php website

Tags: php, cloud, dropbox

I have a website form where users can upload files by simple post method form.
How can I organise moving uploaded files from my web server to my dropbox account?
I try to use PHP SDK listed in dorpbox.com, but this libraries not working as web app.

```
if (PHP_SAPI !== "cli") {
    throw new \Exception("This program was meant to be run from the command-line and not as a web app.  Bad value for PHP_SAPI.  Expected \"cli\", given \"".PHP_SAPI."\".");
}
```

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/start/php

Comment: The sample you're using was designed for the cli, but the Dropbox PHP SDK does support web apps too. I recommend looking at the "web-file-browser" example app included with the SDK: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/sdks/php